# Data gets lost while inserting values in database from csv

Tags: php

I have tried and seen a lot from stackoverflow, yet I am confused because data gets lost while inserting values in the database after reading values from csv.

```
function readnewCSVFile($path)
{
    $file_handle = fopen($path, "r");
    $dateformat = date('j') . '.' . date('n') . '.' . date('Y');  
    $line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1000, ",");
    //print_r($line_of_text);die();

    while (($line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) 
    {

        if ($_POST['types'] == 1)
        {
            $category = $line_of_text['5'] . '/' . $line_of_text['6']; //category
            $product_name = htmlentities($line_of_text['1']); //product_name

            insertquery($category, $product_name);

        }

    }
    fclose($file_handle);
}
```

The function insert query is as follows:

```
function insertquery($category,$product_name)
{
    $sql= "insert into table name setcategory='" . $category . ",product_name='" . $product_name . "'";     
    mysql_query($sql);  
}
```

The loop count moves as many times as the sql exists, but still some odd 100 datas are not added to the database.

Please help me out.

Comment: Post relevant code only to get helped easily

Comment: What is being lost?  Data from one or more cells, whole rows, whole columns?  You aren't validating the csv file.  I would, at the minimum, make sure that the file format is valid.  For example:  check to make sure that each row has the same number of cells.

Comment: Whole row gets lost. Suppose a csv has 8000 lines then nearly 100 odd rows doesn't get's added.

Answer (score 1):

Can be a failed query executed by insertquery(....) with some abnormal value ?

You don't check the (if any) return value of the insert operation, maybe some query silently fail